# Swift: how to close alert with textfield

Tags: swift, swiftui

I can't figure out why the alert opens automatically the second time for a split second after dismissing it (with clicking on ok or cancel button). It seems that text field update UI before presentAlert is set to false. How to fix this without the unwanted opening of the alert after dismiss?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click on button to open alert
2. Close alert with OK or cancel button
3. The alert pops up again for a split second, but it shouldn't

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var presentAlert = false
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @Binding var usernameToSave: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Alert") {
            presentAlert = true            
        }
        .alert("Login", isPresented: $presentAlert, actions: {
            TextField("Username", text: $username)
            Button("Login", action: {
            usernameToSave = username
 })
            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel, action: {})
        }, message: {
            Text("Please enter your username and password.")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your issue here, can you specify the exact steps to reproduce?

Comment: I just did, thanks for checking out

Comment: I did that and I don't see the issue. It wont open for the second time. iOS 17 Simulator

Comment: Hm interesting, thank you! I'm on Ios 16,maybe something to do with that. Does it still not open if you add another state variable eg usernameToSave and set it when the button OK (inside action) is tapped?

Comment: It seems to be a random issue, on Ios 17 it also happened the first two times, then it was okay All the time...

Comment: You should use a sheet, not an alert, for data input from the user. It might also be better to have a separate view for the sheet and use a Binding property but start with switching to a sheet.

Comment: Why is that? Sorry, new to swift.. If it is possible to do it in alert, then it should work, right?

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue either, all works well for me.
 Note, are you declaring something like `@State var usernameToSave: String = ""`
 and calling `ContentView(usernameToSave: $usernameToSave)` from your parent view, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I do. But I've tried to get rid of that and it still doesn't work as expected.

Comment: you could try adding `@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss` in `ContentView`
 and using `action: { dismiss() }` for the `Login` and `Cancel` buttons action.

Comment: You can read the [design guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/modality) to learn what Apple recommends.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn’t reproduce the issue, but maybe set the state back to false on submit or cancel?

```
var body: some View {
        Button("Show Alert") {
            presentAlert = true
        }
        .alert("Login", isPresented: $presentAlert, actions: {
            TextField("Username", text: $username)
            Button("Login", action: {
                usernameToSave = username
                presentAlert = false // <- 
            })
            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel, action: {
                presentAlert = false // <- 
            })
        }, message: {
            Text("Please enter your username and password.")
        })
    }
}
```